# python tidylib module error

Tags: python, import, module

when i am importing tidylib in python and executing the program i am getting the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tidylib\__init__.py", line 71, in <module>

        raise OSError("Could not load libtidy using any of these names: %s" % (",".join(LIB_NAMES)))

        OSError: Could not load libtidy using any of these names: libtidy,libtidy.so,libtidy-0.99.so.0,cygtidy-0-99-0,tidylib,libtidy.dylib,tidy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that libtidy.so is on your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It looks like python is trying to import tidy correctly, but one of the libraries that tidy uses cannot be found.

If using windows, from the [PyTidy docs](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html):

> Windows: (Use PyTidyLib version 0.2 or later!) Prebuilt HTML Tidy DLLs are available from at least two locations. The int64.org Tidy Binaries page provides binaries that were built in 2005, for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, against a patched version of the source. The HTML Tidy web site links to a DLL built in 2006, for 32-bit Windows only, using the vanilla source (scroll near the bottom to “Other Builds” – use the one that reads “exe/lib/dll”, not the “exe”-only version.)
>
> Once you have a DLL (which may be named tidy.dll, libtidy.dll, or tidylib.dll), you must place it in a directory on your system path. If you are running Python from the command-line, placing the DLL in the present working directory will work, but this is unreliable otherwise (e.g. for server software).

So once you have that dll, add its location (ex. C:/myfiles/somethingelse/libtidy.dll) to windows' PATH, from [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15ZLK/):

> 1. Right-click on the My Computer icon. (Under Windows XP, Vista, or Windows 7, the My Computer Icon may be located in the start menu.)
> 2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
>      (Alternatively, you can double-click on the System icon in the Control Panel)
> 3. Click the Advanced tab or "Advanced system settings" on Windows Vista or Windows 7
> 4. Click the Environment Variables button.
> 5. Click on the variable called 'Path' and then click on Edit. Now add the target directory to the value of the variable, using a semi-colon as a separator.
>
> For example, if you want to add the path to MATLAB/bin to your system, which if located at c:\matlab\bin, you would enter the following at the end of the Path:
>
> ;c:\matlab\bin

DONT FORGET THE SEMICOLON

Comment: I assumed you were using linux. Are you on windows or mac?

Comment: These instruction you ask for are included in the answer... make sure you have the semicolon to separate multiple paths, make sure you edit PATH and not SYSTEMPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but on Linux (Alpine 3.8 Docker container). It was unable to find tiny even though I had `tidyhtml` and `tidyhtml-libs` installed in Alpine and `pytidylib` in Python 3.

After seeing this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369946 I installed the Alpine `tidyhtml-dev` package which (suprisingly) made it work.

Answer (score -1):

Though the accepted answer is valid for this issue with Windows, the best way to solve this on Linux is to use a package manager to install one of the missing libraries.

For example, on CentOS7 I had to use

```
sudo yum install -y php-tidy
```

Which was mentioned in this blog post: http://www.linuxspy.info/2262/html-tidy-installation-for-wordpress-w3-total-cache-plugin/

Comment: question is about python